# How to switch from SQL Server to MySQL for using with Excel pivot

Tags: mysql, sql-server, excel, migration

I have a table that contains sales transaction (~20 mil rows). Previously I used SQL Server and export it to an Excel pivot. Data refresh took 10-15 minutes but still do-able. However, after I migrated to MySQL (using XamppLite & ODBC), it took forever to refresh the data in the Excel pivot.

Maybe I didn't optimize the MySQL good enough ? Anyone can share some thoughts 'bout this ?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like both systems need better indexing... It shouldn't take 10-15 minutes to process 20M rows.

Bear in mind that the story going forward (with PowerPivot) is very promising for this scenario.

Comment: Hi,

I'm currently evaluating PowerPivot and it fits our needs so well. Just 1 show-stopper : the PowerPivot cannot be opened by other laptop (with standard corporate Excel 2003).

Is there anyway to convert PowerPivot to normal pivot for Excel 2003/Excel 2007 ?

Thanks

Comment: Hmm... with the coming version of SharePoint it works very nicely. Check out some of the demonstrations that are online.